# knitr kable text color not rendering

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, textcolor, kable

I am new to Rmarkdown and trying to generate a table that has some conditional text formatting. The table comes out as what I want except for the color. It displays \textcolor{red}{50} for example instead of 50 in red. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

In my R script:

```
 table2 <- data %>% filter(student == 1) %>%
           dplyr::mutate(grade = cell_spec(grade, "latex", color = ifelse(grade > 75, "blue", "red"))
```

In my Rmarkdown file:

````
 ```{r, results = "asis"}
 kable(table2, format = "latex")
 ```
````

Comment: I've figured out how to solve my problem. For some reason, if I add use ```{r kable, results = "asis"} kable(table2, format = "latex") my code works as I intended it to.

Answer (score 4):

Your question isn't reproducible, but it appears the issue is that you didn't include `escape = FALSE` in the call to `kable`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
data <- data.frame(student = rep(1:5, 2), grade = sample(100, 10))
table2 <- data %>% filter(student == 1) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(grade = cell_spec(grade, "latex", 
                                  color = ifelse(grade > 75, "blue", "red"))) 
kable(table2, format = "latex", escape = FALSE)
```

Comment: When I add in the escape = FALSE, I get this error:  Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \let \hskip \vskip \let \vrule \hrule \let...
l.210 \hline

Comment: I didn't.  If you would post a reproducible example, maybe someone could help you.